# get or read attachments of SharePoint via web service in Windows-8-Application

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio, sharepoint, windows-8

I am creating a "Windows 8 Application" (Windows Metro_style App) (Windows Store App) in C# by using  "Visual Studio 2012 for Windows". it should connect to a SharePoint Web service and get the data of the list.

I have used the ListData.svc Web service to get the items of the list, texts, titles and everything else but not the Images or Documents or attachments from the SharePoint.

but I did another application with "Visual Studio 2012 for Desktop" which I used the List.asmx web service and I can get any attachments and images.

I do not know how to do this for the windows8 application, because I can not "add web reference" to "Visual Studio 2012 for Windows".

I would be very thankful for any helps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert image/files to binary string format and embed that inside the response. However, when your file sizes are too big, the response time of your web service will be increased. Best way to do this, pass the url's of those files with the response.
For example;
You can pass the image urls in your web service response, and simply set this url to source property of the image control. Windows 8 will download the images asynchronously from that url. Also, you can use BackgroundDownloader for other type of files.